# How to add another patient to the form using existing row?

Tags: angular, angular8

I am new to angular 8 and I want to add another patient to the form through a button, what is the easiest way to do so?
I have created a form in html and bootstrapped and added validation accordingly. A quick google searched showed me that I need to do it through FormArray, but I do not want to change my already existing code in the project

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="patientForm" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="GoToCheckin(f)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="sel1">Your selected Doctor:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <select class="form-control" id="sel1" formControlName="doctor">
        <option *ngFor="let Dr of configDr" [ngValue]="Dr.name">{{ Dr.name }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <p>ETA: {{ waitingTime }} min</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" formControlName="email" />
      <span *ngIf="!patientForm.get('email').valid && patientForm.get('email').touched" class="help-block">
        This feild is required!
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Phone Number:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Enter phone #" formControlName="phone" />
      <span *ngIf="!patientForm.get('phone').valid && patientForm.get('phone').touched" class="help-block">
        This feild is required!
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">First name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter First Name" formControlName="fname" />
      <span *ngIf="!patientForm.get('fname').valid && patientForm.get('fname').touched" class="help-block">
        This feild is required!
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Last name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" formControlName="lname" />
      <span *ngIf="!patientForm.get('lname').valid && patientForm.get('lname').touched" class="help-block">
        This feild is required!
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Reason for visit:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <textarea class="form-control" id="reason" rows="5" placeholder="Enter Reason"
        formControlName="reason"></textarea>
      <span *ngIf="!patientForm.get('reason').valid && patientForm.get('reason').touched" class="help-block">
        This feild is required!
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-4">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"  [disabled]="!patientForm.valid">Check-in</button>
      <span *ngIf="!patientForm.valid && patientForm.touched" class="help-block">
        Please fill in all the fields!
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

```js
export class PatientInfoComponent implements OnInit {

  configDr: Config[];
  patientForm: FormGroup;
  selectedDoctor: string;
  waitingTime: number;
  dropDownDr: string;
  constructor(private router: Router, private TimeService: ETAService, private EmployeeData: EmpData, private DrService: DrdataService) {
    this.DrService.selectedDr.subscribe(tempDr => {
      if (!tempDr) {
        this.selectedDoctor = 'Any Doctor';
      } else {
        this.selectedDoctor = tempDr;
      }
    }
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.showConfig();
    this.patientForm = new FormGroup({
      doctor: new FormControl(this.selectedDoctor),
      email: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      phone: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      fname: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      lname: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      reason: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
    });
  }

  GoToCheckin(f: NgForm) {
    this.TimeService.waiting_time = this.waitingTime;
    this.router.navigate(['checkedin']);
  }

  showConfig() {
    this.EmployeeData.getConfig()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.configDr = data as Config[];

        for (let count = 0; count < this.configDr.length; ++count) {
          if (this.configDr[count].name === this.selectedDoctor) {
            this.waitingTime = this.configDr[count].eta;
            return;
          }
        }
      });
  }

  public timeChange() {
    console.log("Selected doctor: " + this.patientForm.get('doctor').value);
    for (let count = 0; count < this.configDr.length; ++count) {
      if (this.patientForm.get('doctor').value === this.configDr[count].name) {
        this.waitingTime = this.configDr[count].eta;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `FormArray` is the way to go if you want to add multiple elements of the same type (especially if you do not know the exact amount). What have you tried so far regarding `FormArray`?

Comment: @Scorpioo590 I have tried following this: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-add-person-eg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). But I can not figure out how to move the formcontrol that I have already declared and add those to the `FormArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really it's easy. You move your code patienForm to a function, and declare a FormArray

```
myFormArray:FormArray=new FormArray([]);

newPatient()
{
   return new FormGroup({
      doctor: new FormControl(this.selectedDoctor),
      email: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      phone: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      fname: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      lname: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      reason: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
    });
}
```

Your .html like

```
<div *ngFor="let patientForm of myFormArray.controls [formGroup]="patientForm ">
    ...all your code under tag form that you had before...
</div>
```

And in ngOnInit

```
this.myFormArray.push(this.newPatient())
```

Each new patien only need make a push like in ngOnInit. To remove simple use

```
 this.myFormArray.removeAt(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Patient form in a seperate component (patient-component) and repeat that component. Something like this

```
<ng-container  *ngFor="let patient in patientList"
<patient-component [patientData]="patient" ><patient-component>
<ng-container>
```

The patientData will be the form data.

Comment: it's a very very bad idea. imagine that you has severals submit buttons, e.g. you can send all the patiens together, etc.